# How was the cow with broken neck disposed of? Deuteronomy 21

Tags: halacha, murder, deuteronomy

About the cow with the broken neck in [Deut 21](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.21.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), I can't find out what happened to the cow after the ritual was completed.

Was the cow

- given as a gift to the family of the victim, so they could eat it?
- eaten by someone else?
- left to rot in the field?
- burned?
- buried?

When thinking about disposal, would the cow with the broken neck be an unclean cattle carcass (Lev 5.2) that you could not touch? In that case, disposal might be difficult but leaving it to rot would also be bad. One would need to burn it without touching it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the Rambam's Mishne Torah [Hilchot Rotzeach uShmirat Nefesh 10:6](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1088926/jewish/Rotzeach-uShmirat-Nefesh-Chapter-Ten.htm)

> It is forbidden to benefit from a calf that is decapitated. **It should
> be buried at the place where it was decapitated.**

See the original for further details of the law.